# Error with datanucleus enhancer

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, datanucleus

I'm on windows 7 using eclipse and the datanucleus enhancer for a gwt + gae app. When I want to deploy I have got this error message:

```
'DataNucleus Enhacer' has encountred a problem

Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\Source\git\cp"): CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\Source\git\cp"): CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.ProcessUtilities.launchProcessAndActivateOnError(ProcessUtilities.java:280)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.orm.enhancement.EnhancerJob.runInWorkspace(EnhancerJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 4 more
```

I've had this problem before, and it was due to a long classpath. I just spent time shortening my classpath by moving libraries around and even moving my gwt and appengine SDKs, but with no luck.
Any ideas about where I should start to look for an answer?